# I have a Laravel file permission error on an app deploy on cpanel

Tags: php, laravel

I have deployed laravel app on a cpanel but I get this error when  I try to access the app
The stream or file "/home2/../public_html/../../storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Read-only file system.

Am unable to set the file permission on the cpanel.

Please does any one have a way I can go around this ? Thanks

Comment: you need to delete the log files in your project

Comment: I think  the issue might be from the  host provider because it does not allow me delete it  an I cant even rename

Comment: `/../storage/logs/laravel.log` file is the log file privided by laravel itself. You need to give it edit permission. Or, your cPanel file limit/usage crossed.

Comment: If I try to edit the permission I get  this error FileOp Failure: 
 • The system failed to change the permissions for logs with the error: Read-only file system

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant read access to storage folder.

```
chmod -R 775 storage
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command,
its work for me!

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw storage
```